# Load html from external file via ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I need in my project to load some html from external file like you see in below code this my php code

```
if(strtolower($_SERVER["request_method"]) == "get") {
    $html = "";
    $path = $_GET["path"];
    if($path == "cities-select-options") {
        $country_code = htmlspecialchars($_GET["country_code"]);
        $get_cities = get_cities($country_code);
        $html .= ' <option value=""> --- </option> ';
        foreach($get_cities as $city):
            $html .= ' <option value="">'.$city["city_name"].'</option> ';
        endforeach;
        echo $html;
    }elseif() {
        /* */
    }
}
```

and this my js code

```
$( "#ad_country" ).on("change",function() {
    $country_id = $(this).val();
    $.get("htmlLoader.php?path=cities-select-option&country_id="+$country_id,function(html) {
        $("#ad_city").html(html);
    });
});
```

but I'm confused by this method. because I have too many section need to be load via ajax. So my question is : **there is way to do that without writing many if conditions ?**

Comment: You can use `switch($_GET['path'])`

Comment: Why are you calling `htmlspecialchars()`? That should only be used when displaying something on a web page that isn't supposed to be rendered as HTML.

Comment: You never `echo $html;` back to your JavaScript. Nest your AJAX calls.

Comment: @Barmar not it should be HTML code depending on `$path` value

Comment: If all the endpoints are returning different data (rendered html) then yes your need to have if's for each.. if they are not and they are all selects, just map the path to the function and have 1 renderer/loop..

Comment: @LawrenceCherone no I have many different html not only selects

Comment: @joowmss My question was why `$path = htmlspecialchars($_GET["path"]);` instead of just `$path = $_GET["path"];`? You never display `$path` on the page, so it doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: Then your need to handle them...

Comment: @Barmar Habit :) ! all variable is already known i know it no need to use it I update my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the code for each path in different functions, and use an associative array to call them.

```
$paths = array(
    'cities-select-option' => 'get_cities_options',
    'states-select-option' => 'get_states_options',
    ...
);

function get_cities_options() {
    $html = ' <option value=""> --- </option> ';
    $country_code = $_GET["country_code"];
    $get_cities = get_cities($country_code);
    foreach($get_cities as $city):
        $html .= ' <option value="">'.$city["city_name"].'</option> ';
    endforeach;
    return $html;
}

function get_states_options() {
    ...
}

if (strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'get') {
    $path = $_GET['path'];
    if (isset($paths[$path])) {
        echo $paths[$path]();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank  you ! I have one more question for you why you call function `$var()` instead using `call_user_func`

Comment: They're equivalent, but this syntax is simpler.

Comment: if this answer is correct please mark it as such, thank you